# Respimage functionality not working in news Contao

Tags: contao

Hi I need to make responsive images in contao website (https://rocksolidthemes.com/de/contao/blog/responsive-images-picture-contao).  So I created an image size in theme model and add a media query . Add necessary configurations in layout . But it is not working as expected in news .  but working in gallery, image content element . What will be the reason ?

```
    <?php if ($this->addImage): ?>
      <?php $this->arrData['size'] = '17'; $this->addImageToTemplate($this,$this->arrData); ?>
        <?php $this->insert('image', $this->arrData); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
```

image.html5

```
    <?php $this->insert('picture_default', $this->picture); ?>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Without knowing what data is present in your tempate it is impossible to say what you are doing wrong. For instance, in order for your approach to work, your template needs to have a `singleSRC` variable containing the path to the image.

Comment: Thank you for your response . I found an extra variable is set in my template.Its working after removing it